# Type checking string value like "string" & "integer" & "boolean"·

Tags: objective-c

I have strings containing names of types. Therefore it is not instances on the types, I only have the string value describing the type and an input text in string.

```
NSString *text = @"1234";
NSString *type = @"integer";

NSString *text = @"hello there";
NSString *type = @"string";

NSString *text = @"true";
NSString *type = @"bool";
```

How would you check if it is a valid type from the tekst.

Would NSRegularExpression be the right way or how would you do it?

Comment: I guess I'd compare to the literal strings. (Or you can do `[@"_integer_string_bool_" rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"_%@_", type]]` and see if the result is not NSNotFound.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSScanner`, an algorithm in outline :

- Create an instance of `NSScanner` for your `text` string
- Based on the value of your `type` string call the appropriate method of `NSScanner`, e.g. `scanInteger:` for integers and `scanString:intoString:` for booleans (hint: scan for the boolean literals)
- If the scanning method returns `YES` then check the `isAtEnd` method to make sure there is no garbage *after* the scanned value

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I have the following lines of code.

```
- (NSInteger)getStringType:(NSString *)value :(BOOL)a {
    if ([value isEqualToString:@"true"] || [value isEqualToString:@"false"]) {
        return 2;
    }
    else {
        // a: Whether to accept 0
        NSRange range;
        NSString *expression = @"^[1-9][0-9]*$";
        range = [value rangeOfString:expression options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
        if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            if (a == YES) {
                if (value.length == 1 && [value isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the string (value) is boolean, it should return 2.  If it's an integer, it should return 1.  Otherwise, it will return 0.  That is, if it's a string, whether it's empty or not, you'll get 0.  If you want to include '0' as a number, set 'a' to YES.  This function is tested under the **OSX** platform.